# Use ng-click on md-tab label

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

I'm having trouble with `md-tabs` : I can't call a controller function whenever I click on a specific tab to be displayed.

Here are the few codes I tried :

```
<md-tabs md-center-tabs id="menuTabs" md-dynamic-height="true" ng-click="focusSearch()">

            <md-tab label="<i class='fa fa-search'></i>" ng-if="handleResize()">
                <md-content class="control-sidebar-dark" ng-style="{'height' : menuHeight}">
```

and

```
<md-tabs md-center-tabs id="menuTabs" md-dynamic-height="true">

            <md-tab label="<i class='fa fa-search' ng-click='focusSearch()'></i>" ng-if="handleResize()">
                <md-content class="control-sidebar-dark" ng-style="{'height' : menuHeight}">
```

and

```
<md-tabs md-center-tabs id="menuTabs" md-dynamic-height="true">

            <md-tab ng-click="focusSearch()" label="<i class='fa fa-search'></i>" ng-if="handleResize()">
                <md-content class="control-sidebar-dark" ng-style="{'height' : menuHeight}">
```

I want my `focusSearch()` function to be called when I click on this tab but she never is.

Comment: to which controller does it belong ?

Comment: @Creator I got only one app and one controller, my point is I can't use ng-click on the tab.

Comment: can you write plunker for it ?

Comment: Well, I just modified the one from Angular Material website :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJajgW
Just use `ng-click="Test()"` in order to call the function whenever we click to change tabs. Edit : It looks like it works when added in `md-tabs` in the codepen but it doesnt for me, and anyway, I want the function to be called only for one specific tab.

Comment: Ok So instead of using ng-click you can create an directive to listen for click event . http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXJPvx .

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try using these built in `md-tab` attributes

- `md-on-select`
- `md-on-deselect`

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('main', function($scope) {

  $scope.myClickEvent1 = function() {
    alert('one selected');
  }

  $scope.myClickEvent2 = function() {
    alert('two selected');
  }

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="main">
  <md-tabs>
    <md-tab md-on-select="myClickEvent1()">One</md-tab>
    <md-tab md-on-select="myClickEvent2()">Two</md-tab>
  </md-tabs>
</div>
```

**Note:** This event differs slightly from ng-click, in that if a tab is already selected and then clicked, the event will not fire.

Source: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/api/material.components.tabs/directive/mdTab

Answer (score 3):

Like Creator suggested, I ended up using a directive instead of `ng-click` :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXJPvx

Answer (score 0):

I reached here while looking for angular/material 6, i did in this way by following Trevors solution:

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
```

in `.ts` file

```
   tabChanged(event) {
    if (event.tab.textLabel == 'matchingTabName') {
        //do your stuff
    } else {
        //do your stuff
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is a good solution, unfortunately it does not apply here since this question is about AngularJS and not Angular.